# How does geth (execution client) connect to lighthouse (execution client)?

Tags: go-ethereum

During the synchronization process between the consensus client (lighthouse) and the execution client (geth), the error "Beacon client online, but no consensus updates received in a while. Please fix your beacon client to follow the chain!" is reported.[image]